# flat array to tree array

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently stuck on the modification of an array "flat" to a array structure of a tree.

I have an array to the type:

```
$folders = array(
    array('Name' => 'Archive', 'Value' => 'Archive', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
    array('Name' => 'Folder1', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
    array('Name' => 'FolderA', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1/DossierA', 'Attributes' => 64, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
    array('Name' => 'Folder2', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
    array('Name' => 'FolderA', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
    array('Name' => 'FolderB', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA/FolderB', 'Attributes' => 64, 'Delimiters' => '/'),
);
```

and I would get an array to the type:

```
$treefolders = array(
    array('Name' => 'Archive', 'Value' => 'Archive', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/', 'subnode' => 
        array('Name' => 'Folder1', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/', 'subnode' =>
            array('Name' => 'FolderA', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1/FolderA', 'Attributes' => 64, 'Delimiters' => '/')
        ),
        array('Name' => 'Folder2', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/', 'subnode' => 
            array('Name' => 'FolderA', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA', 'Attributes' => 32, 'Delimiters' => '/', 'subnode' =>
                array('Name' => 'FolderB', 'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA/FolderB', 'Attributes' => 64, 'Delimiters' => '/')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I do not know how to get to the last result.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, in PHP arrays cannot be used as array keys. You are able to use just the directory name as a key.

The best solution is to change the way you create your array or rethink your code and/or data structure. There is probably a much easier solution to your problem, maybe re-ask your question. See the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have done anything in my first post

Here is the structure of my array "flat":

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Archive'
            'Value' => 'Archive'
            'Attributes' => 32
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
    [1] =>
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Folder1'
            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1'
            'Attributes' => 32
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
    [2] =>
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'FolderA'
            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1/DossierA'
            'Attributes' => 64
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
    [3] =>
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Folder2'
            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2'
            'Attributes' => 32
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
   [4] =>
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'FolderA'
            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA'
            'Attributes' => 32
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
   [5] =>
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'FolderB'
            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2FolderA/FolderB'
            'Attributes' => 64
            'Delimiters' => '/'
        )    
)
```

And that I am seeking:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
        Array
        (
            'Name' => 'Archive'
            'Value' => 'Archive'
            'Attributes' => 32
            'Delimiters' => '/'
            'SubNode' =>
                Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                        Array
                        (
                            'Name' => 'Folder1'
                            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1'
                            'Attributes' => 32
                            'Delimiters' => '/'
                            'SubNode' =>
                                Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 
                                        Array
                                        (
                                            'Name' => 'FolderA'
                                            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder1/DossierA'
                                            'Attributes' => 64
                                            'Delimiters' => '/'
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                    [1] =>
                        Array
                        (
                            'Name' => 'Folder2'
                            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2'
                            'Attributes' => 32
                            'Delimiters' => '/'
                            'SubNode' =>
                                Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 
                                        Array
                                        (
                                            'Name' => 'FolderA'
                                            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA'
                                            'Attributes' => 32
                                            'Delimiters' => '/'
                                            'SubNode' =>
                                                Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => 
                                                        Array
                                                        (
                                                            'Name' => 'FolderB'
                                                            'Value' => 'Archive/Folder2/FolderA/FolderB'
                                                            'Attributes' => 64
                                                            'Delimiters' => '/'
                                                        )    
                                                )    
                                        )    
                                )    
                        )    
                )    
        )    
)
```

The normally its should be possible ^^